# What do you call a person who hates own offspring?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there word in English that describes a person who hates or dislikes his/her own children?

Comment: ...maybe a monster?

Comment: A mesopedist hates children. (Perhaps especially their own?)

Comment: A (long-suffering) parent?

Comment: Is it warranted or unwarranted?

Comment: Misopaedist is right.  It is in the OED.  It is from μισόπαις --
https://philolog.us/lsj/%CE%BC%CE%B9%CF%83%E1%BD%B9%CF%80%CE%B1%CE%B9%CF%82
-- which was (at least once) used specifically of hating one's own
children.  -- Can't answer, since for some reason this perfectly clear
question was closed.  My attempt to add an example of usage was also, for some incomprehensible reason, rejected.